# code after fadeTo() animation effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, fadeto

I created a menu [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/KMwqm/)
And I'm trying to apply fadeTo() the code you see below, but the 4th line doesn't work anymore. How can I apply fadeTo without affecting the hovered element just like in the link I provided? thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").hover(function(){
      $("#menubar a").fadeTo(1000, .7);
      $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");    /* doesn't work with fadeTo*/
      }, function(){
        $("#menubar a").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the current object

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/KMwqm/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").hover(function () {
        $("#menubar a").not(this).fadeTo(1000, .1);
    }, function () {
        $("#menubar a").not(this).fadeTo(1000, .7);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have just read .not() removes elements from the set of matched elements.  Thank you thank you thank you so much...